# Adding two columns with dates in R

Tags: r, date, addition

I have two columns of dates and I need to sum those columns for each row of the data, for example:

```
a <- c("A","B","C")
b <- c("2016-01-19 11:06:00", "2016-01-30 17:22:00","2016-02-07 13:21:00")
a=as.data.frame(a)
b=as.data.frame(b)
c=cbind(a,b)
c$newcol <- rep("0000-00-00 00:01:00",nrow(c))

#   a                   b              newcol
# 1 A 2016-01-19 11:06:00 0000-00-00 00:01:00
# 2 B 2016-01-30 17:22:00 0000-00-00 00:01:00
# 3 C 2016-02-07 13:21:00 0000-00-00 00:01:00
```

What is the easiest way to make a new column with sum of columns `b` and `newcol`?

Comment: Convert the 'b' and 'newcol' to class `Datetime` (POSIXct) and then do the sum.  What is the expected output?

Comment: If you want to add an hour to the `datetime` in column b consider using `lubridate` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html
If column b is `POSIXct` you can just do:
`b + hours(1)` to add 1 hour

Comment: What all of this `as.data.frame` on single columns and then `cbind` mess? Just do `df1 <- data.frame(a = c("A","B","C"), b = c("2016-01-19 11:06:00", "2016-01-30 17:22:00","2016-02-07 13:21:00"))`. If you convert to `POSIXct` class (as suggested by @akrun) this is a matter of just `with(df1, b + newcol)` and it will be summed by row.

Comment: i tried to do that at first, but I always got the same error, that '+' is not meaningful for factors.

Comment: You need to **convert** to `POSIXct` class....